# Как узнать, где находится папка documents с помощью python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10

Мне надо что-бы программа автоматически находила путь к папке Documents и записывала путь в переменную user.
Как мне это сделать?
Нужно, чтобы находило именно путь, а не имя пользователя.

Comment: Попробуйте это https://stackoverflow.com/a/3927493/5909792

Comment: О какой OS идёт речь в вопросе?

Comment: Window 10 64-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как по мне, то можно и так (меньше кода/более читаемый):

```
import os
user = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Documents')
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно получить из реестра:

```
from winreg import *

aReg = ConnectRegistry(None, HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders")
name = QueryValueEx(aKey, 'Personal')[0]
print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно получить из WinAPI функции `SHGetSpecialFolderPathW`:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes.wintypes import MAX_PATH

CSIDL_PERSONAL = 5

shell32 = ctypes.windll.shell32
buf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(MAX_PATH + 1)
shell32.SHGetSpecialFolderPathW(None, buf, CSIDL_PERSONAL, False)
print(buf.value)
```